# D3 v5: "d" attribute in <path> tag not populating with values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently trying to create a simple line chart with D3 but I'm having some difficulties getting the data to display. The code seems to work (axes are generated fine) but for some reason, the "d" attribute in the  tag is nonexistent when I run the code. The "fill," "stroke," and "stroke-width" attributes show up fine.

It appears that the line generator function I created is never used (see the console.logs below). I'm also not getting any errors.

```
d3.csv("./data/myFile.csv").then(d => {
        return { 
            percentile: d.percentile, 
            y50: +d.y50
        };
    }).then(data => {
        var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
            .domain(myDomain)
            .range([0, width])
            .padding(.5);
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 100])
            .range([height, 0]);
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

        let line = d3.line()
            .x(d => {
                console.log("THIS DOES NOT PRINT TO CONSOLE");
                return xScale(d.percentile);
            })
            .y(d => {return yScale(d.y50)});

        console.log('THIS PRINTS TO CONSOLE');

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);

        console.log('THIS PRINTS TO CONSOLE');
    });
```

This is what I see in the browser (I expect there to be a "d=..." attribute as well):

```
<path fill="none" stroke="steelblue" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
```

Edit: Here's a screenshot of what I see in the browser:
[image: Screenshot]

Here's the first few rows of data:

```
percentile,y50
P0-10,16.10
P10-20,17.10
P20-30,18.50
P30-40,19.00
P40-50,19.20
```

Comment: What is in the `./data/myFile.csv` file? Have you tried to `console.log` the data to ensure it's being loaded as you expect?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what the graph looks like or even a jsfiddle? Is this a line chart, right? does your percentile have a "%" at the end of each item? Also if you check in the developer tools and highlight over the path, where on your screen does chrome think your path is?

Comment: Oh, gotcha. So d attribute is not even written to.

Comment: @JD333, I added a screenshot of my browser to the post!

Comment: @Tom, myFile.csv has a "percentile" column w/ strings that represent income percentiles, and a "y50" column with the tax rate (percent * 100) for each income percentile. 
EDIT: Actually, the data is not being loaded as I expect. When I console.log(data) right below the second .then(), percentile is undefined and y50 is NaN

Comment: Use data instead of datum.. did you try this?

Comment: data instead of datum doesn't work, but I see that my issue is that my "data" parameter in the second .then() is empty. Do you know how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: It's a little hard to tell without the contents of the csv file, or the output of console.log. But I think what might be happening is that you're returning an object rather than mapping over the result collection. Try changing your first return to be: `return d.map(item => ({ percentile: item.percentile, y50: +item.y50 }));`

Comment: I think what I would've done in the first then is to just loop through the data. In the same then() after you loop through the array, create the graph. I think I'm thinking of the same thing @Tom is saying. If you console.log(data); in the second then you'll see your problem.

Comment: @Tom: that worked! Thanks Tom and JD333 for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d3.csv("./data/myFile.csv").then(data => {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y50 = +d.y50;
      });
        var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
            .domain(myDomain)
            .range([0, width])
            .padding(.5);
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

        var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 100])
            .range([height, 0]);
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));

        let line = d3.line()
            .x(d => {
                console.log("THIS DOES NOT PRINT TO CONSOLE");
                return xScale(d.percentile);
            })
            .y(d => {return yScale(d.y50)});

        console.log('THIS PRINTS TO CONSOLE');

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("d", line)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);

        console.log('THIS PRINTS TO CONSOLE');
    });
```

This should fix your problem. You're original second then statement never retained the transformed data in your first then statement.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the problem that was found here in the comments for future reference:

Rather than converting all the returned rows into the expected data format, the first `.then` is just returning a single object with:

```
{ 
    percentile: undefined, 
    y50: NaN
}
```

What needs to happen here is to loop, or map, over the original data, and return the transformed object for each row i.e.

```
.then(data => {
    return data.map(d => {
        return { percentile: d.percentile, y50: +d.y50 }
    }
));
```